# Java printing a String containing an integer

Tags: java, string, println

I have a doubt which follows.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
  int number=1;
  System.out.println("M"+number+1);
}
```

**Output:**  `M11`

But I want to get it printed M2 instead of M11. I couldn't number++ as the variable is involved with a for loop, which gives me different result if I do so and couldn't print it using another print statement, as the output format changes.

Requesting you to help me how to print it properly.

Comment: you will need to do something like this: `System.out.println("M"+(number+1))`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.out.printf("M%d%n", number+1);
```

Where `%n` is a newline

Answer (score 13):

Add a bracket around your sum, to enforce the `sum` to happen first. That way, your `bracket` having the highest precedence will be evaluated first, and then the `concatenation` will take place.

```
System.out.println("M"+(number+1));
```

Answer (score 6):

It has to do with the precedence order in which java concatenates the String,

Basically Java is saying

- `"M"+number = "M1"`
- `"M1"+1 = "M11"`

You can overload the precedence just like you do with maths

```
"M"+(number+1)
```

This now reads

- `"M"+(number+1)` = `"M"+(1+1)` = `"M"+2` = `"M2"`

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
System.out.println("M"+(number+1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
System.out.println("M"+(number+1));
```

Comment: Oh, what a dump I am! Thanks a lot, Zaheer.

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner way to separate data from invariants:

```
int number=1;
System.out.printf("M%d%n",number+1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  System.out.println("M"+number+1);
```

String concatination in java works this way:

if the first operand is of  type String and you use `+` operator, it concatinates the next operand and the result would be a String.

try

```
 System.out.println("M"+(number+1));
```

In this case as the `()` paranthesis have the highest precedence the things inside the brackets would be evaluated first. then the resulting int value would be concatenated with the String literal resultingin a string "M2"

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println("M"+number+1);`

Here You are using `+` as a concatanation Operator as Its in the `println()` method.

To use `+` to do sum, You need to Give it high Precedence which You can do with covering it with brackets as Shown Below:

`System.out.println("M"+(number+1));`

Answer (score 0):

If you perform `+` operation after a string, it takes it as concatenation:

```
"d" + 1 + 1     // = d11
```

Whereas if you do the vice versa `+` is taken as addition:

```
1 + 1 + "d"     // = 2d
```